# hitTest:withEvent: is calling sendActionsForControlEvents twice

Tags: ios, uibutton, hittest

I have a simple UIButton subclass and I just want to extend the touch area of the button without actually increasing the frame (this is because I want the highlight and selected backgrounds to be the size of the original frame).

Here is what I have added to my UIButton subclass:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    int errorMargin = 20;
    CGRect largerFrame = CGRectMake(0 - (errorMargin / 2), 0 - (errorMargin / 2), self.frame.size.width + errorMargin, self.frame.size.height + errorMargin);

    if ((CGRectContainsPoint(largerFrame, point)) == 1){

        NSLog(@"Sending Action");
        [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        return self;
    }
    else{
        return nil;
    }

}
```

This works great; however, it is calling the required action twice. So for instance a "tab" button will be tapped once, but tab over twice.

I have found a few questions related to a UIControl and the beganTracking method, but I can't get it to work with a UIButton.

Any ideas on how to properly implement this with a UIButton? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried just returning `self` for the larger area, without calling `sendActions...`?

Comment: Worked like a charm! In-fact, now that I look at it, I don't know why I didn't think of that. If you can add an actual answer I will gladly select it so you get credit. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By returning `self` for the larger area, you can fool the `hitTest` logic into thinking that the button is larger than it is. That should cause the button to trigger the action without the need to call `sendActionsForControlEvents` in the `hitTest` method.